# Subprocess won't exit if it is created by WSGI script

Tags: python, subprocess, wsgi

I have this code snippet from a web app, and could run & exit normally if I execute this from command line. But if it is issued by a http request, the subprocess will not exit.

```py
import subprocess


def test_build():
    msg = 'msg'
    make_code = '/opt/arduino/arduino-builder -compile -and-many-other-options -verbose /tmp/arduino-sketch-7c17cb3749d67dadaded5c7edc6ca63b/main.ino'
    try:
        ps = subprocess.Popen(make_code,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        msg = ps.stderr.read()
        exc_code = ps.wait()
        # print(msg) # for debug only
        # print(exc_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error with build", str(e) + msg)

test_build()
```

This **only** happens when specific codes are added to `main.ino`.

The problem is disappeared after I change `subprocess.Popen(make_code,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)` to `subprocess.Popen(make_code,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)`, but I could not figure out why this would happen.

Is there any difference for the subprocess if it is forked by a web app?

Comment: I would guess that the process is generating a significant amount of STDOUT text.  If that's directed to a pipe, but you aren't reading your end of the pipe, the process is quickly going to block and be unable to finish.

Comment: @jasonharper Do you mean the subprocess will be piped to the shell's STDOUT if run from command line, but will not if created by http request? I set `shell=True` and I thought it should be the same with running from command line.

Comment: Neither the `shell=` option nor the environment you run the code in should make any   difference.  I expect the difference is entirely in what you're telling arduino-builder to do: compiling a simple program that doesn't generate any warnings may produce little enough output that it all fits into the pipe's buffer, and therefore doesn't block the process.  You should probably be using `ps.communicate()` to read from both STDOUT and STDERR simultaneously, so the problem can't occur.

Comment: I mean even with the same main.ino file that could block the process from the web app, the above script could exit normally when I run from command line. Maybe it is because the output buffer sizes for these two env are different?